# Does Guillermo Ochoa have six fingers on his right hand?

Tags: anatomy

http://www.friendsoffulham.com/forum/index.php?topic=8451.0

http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/606/A82916067

The claim is that Guillermo Ochoa has six fingers on his right hand. Is this true?

[image: Guillermo Ochoa]

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_obYKUcLh-dg/Sp8AE_YELsI/AAAAAAAAAAk/D2z8_d1vOok/s400/memo_ochoa.jpg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No:

[image]

Photograph from [Memo Ochoa no tiene pensado regresar](http://www.las5.mx/noticia/7478/memo-ochoa-no-tiene-pensado-regresar)

> His first link had a photo too. Maybe this is photoshoped

[Other images of him](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&q=Guillermo+Ochoa+hand) show the usual number of fingers.

Also [The Province reported](http://blogs.theprovince.com/2014/06/17/mexican-goalkeeper-guillermo-ochoa-does-not-have-six-fingers-on-his-right-hand/):

> Mexican goalkeeper Guillermo Ochoa does NOT have six fingers on his right hand.

It's possible that they're all photo-shopped; it's even possible that everything you see on the 'net is filtered/altered by the Illuminati before it reaches you: possible, but not probable, IMO.

Comment: His first link had a photo too. Maybe this is photoshoped.

Comment: This answer does need some better sources - maybe something more definitive could be found from this: http://blogs.theprovince.com/2014/06/17/mexican-goalkeeper-guillermo-ochoa-does-not-have-six-fingers-on-his-right-hand/

Comment: or you can show the original image, with just 5 fingers: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_obYKUcLh-dg/Sp8AE_YELsI/AAAAAAAAAAk/D2z8_d1vOok/s400/memo_ochoa.jpg

Comment: It's amazing how one person can photoshop a single photo, and get that many people to believe it. When many other photos point to the contrary.

Comment: @Cruncher For reference, I don't actually believe he has six fingers. But one random photo hardly beats another.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman Oh I agree. If it was 1 versus 1 it would be a different story. But almost all of the pictures has him with 5 fingers

Comment: Much better answer with the edits.